# how does apache commons-cli parses \\t character

Tags: shell, command-line, command-line-interface, backslash, apache-commons-cli

I need to pass tab as an argument in commons-cli. When I give the argument as "\\t", the command line parser parses it as "\t" character itself but not TAB (        ) white space. How can I achieve this?

**Edit :**

As suggested by @centic, updating the question with how am I calling the application. I am calling using command line in Unix where a backslash is detected as an escape character.

More precisely, I am using it while submitting hadoop streaming jobs, if this helps. For eg :

hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.4.0.jar -D stream.map.output.field.separator="\t" -file mapper.py -mapper mapper.py -file reducer.py -reducer reducer.py -input /in -output /out

Apache Hadoop uses Apache Commons-cli as command line utility. So I am assuming "\\t" resolves to "\t" and passed as an option. But when I print it by debugging hadoop source code, instead of a TAB white space character, it prints as a "\t" (string literal) itself.

Comment: Did you try "    ", i.e. an actual tab in quotes?

Comment: My objective is to know how commons-cli parses backslash itself. Am I correct using \\\t which I am assuming after parsing resolves to \\t which is tab (white space character) according to UTF-8 character set? If not, Why cannot I use special characters like \\t, \\n as white space characters? How else would you achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can edit the question and list how exactly you are calling the application. There are other pieces which could interfere, e.g. the shell on unix typically also interprets backslash as escape-char and thus things might already get corrupted there for you...

Comment: @centic - Updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to provide this when invoking the application in the shell, this is actually related to how the shell handles such special characters, not commons-cli or Java.

The [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) shell (which is the default shell on most unix/linux versions nowadays) has the special syntax `$'\t'` for this, see [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) in the manual.

So your call would be something like

```
HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.4.0.jar -D 
stream.map.output.field.separator=$'\t' -file mapper.py -mapper 
mapper.py -file reducer.py -reducer reducer.py -input /in -output /out
```